# ImportError: DLL load failed: The file cannot be accessed by the system

Tags: python, pycharm

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-a40793f9ded7>", line 7, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from .base import clone

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from .isolve import *

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _iterative

ImportError: DLL load failed: The file cannot be accessed by the system.
```

Got this error while trying to run some already used python scripts on pycharm. Has anybody had this error before and has he solved it? It started after I installed a package in python but never used it. The problem is located when I try to import train_test_split on scikit-learn and tensorflow, the sklearn package and seaborn. The other parts of the code seem unaffected.
I have already reinstalled anaconda and python as well as changing the python files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What PyCharm version do you use?

Comment: PyCharm Community Edition 3.3 2019. I resolved the issue with the interpreter as well. I do not like guessing, but it would seem that there was a dependency issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reinstalling the python as well as updating all the packages (conda update --all) and changing the PATH file, it seems that the issue is solved in all of my IDE's except PyCharm. It seems that all that remains is an interpreter issue. I will post updates if something else comes into my attention.