# Python sklearn import error (DLL load failed: The file cannot be accessed by the system.)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network, pip

I have been trying to load the sklearn module in jupyter-notebook pycharm and Idea all shows the same error. I tried reinstalling the IDE's and also Python (3.7) but the error did not go. I just started learning neural networks and have not been able to solve it on my own.

**My Code**

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
```

**Error**

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-50de83ae6761> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 from random import randint
----> 3 from sklearn.utils import shuffle

c:\users\guhan.b\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     78     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     79     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 80     from .base import clone
     81     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     82 

.....

c:\users\guhan.b\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>
    177 
    178 from scipy._lib.six import callable, string_types
--> 179 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
    180 from scipy.ndimage import measurements
    181 from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion

c:\users\guhan.b\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py in <module>
     97 from .kdtree import *
     98 from .ckdtree import *
---> 99 from .qhull import *
    100 from ._spherical_voronoi import SphericalVoronoi
    101 from ._plotutils import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The file cannot be accessed by the system.
```

The error message was very long, I was not able to fit the full error.

Comment: have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617135/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-file-cannot-be-accessed-by-the-system

Comment: yes i did see that and i tried reinstalling and changing path but i didn't work. I'm not using anaconda distribution

Comment: Did you install the normal version of numpy available using `pip install numpy`? Or did you install the numpy+mkl version? If you just installed numpy, then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34579309/7363404